# switch case skip two same letter

Tags: javascript

I have been trying for a while i am printing the vowels first than all the consonants but when two same letters come consecutively it ignore or skip the second letter.

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    var arr = s.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        switch (arr[i]) {
            case "a":
            case "o":
            case "i":
            case "u":
            case "e":
                console.log(arr[i]);
                arr.splice(i, 1);
                break;
        } 
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        switch (arr[i]) {
            default:
                console.log(arr[i]);
                break;
        } 
    }
}

vowelsAndConsonants("teen");
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have 5 blank cases?

Comment: can't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you delete the letter in the array, and the values get shifted to the left. This means that after `i++` runs, you will skip the vowel after the one deleted. After `arr.splice(i, 1);` you can add `i--`.

Comment: Thanks Man! very much i didnt see that